# why does client-js to display data from a api doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

**[Entire Code](https://github.com/rushilhacker1/Irrational-Mathematics/)**
the code is supposed to display all the names of files in /constants directory  which works but then it should display value of the file which does not work
i tried troubleshooting for approx 4 hours or even more

my opnion of error part

```js
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            const constantLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.lst');
            const constantValue = document.getElementById('constantValue');

            constantLinks.forEach(link =>
                link.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    fetch('https://localhost:3000/data/' + this.textContent.split('(')[0])
                        .then(response => response.text())
                        .then(value => {
                            constantValue.textContent = value;
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.error('Error:' + error);
                        });

                }
                )
            )
        });
```

**[what i was  expecting](https://irrationalmathematics.rf.gd)**
the website is a different and slower way to do same thing with php and i am trying to replace it with node
i tried to use console.logs and it just doesn't work

Comment: change `https://localhost:3000/data/` to `http://localhost:3000/data/`

Comment: Bro its https only

Comment: Check app.js on entire code github link

Comment: dude, your git link is invalid

Comment: Sorry the repo was private

Comment: I made it public now

Comment: try disabling your certificate check, as your's is not a valid signed cert

Answer (score 0):

try disabling your certificate check, as it is not a valid signed cert

```js
const https = require('https');

fetch('https://localhost:3000/data/' + this.textContent.split('(')[0], {
    agent
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(value => {
    constantValue.textContent = value;
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:' + error);
});
```

Comment: this does not work but a kind of messy way is on github that works

Comment: if u can help cleanup i will appreciate it . i think it is not the proper way

Comment: @RushilGupta or you could install the certificate on your machine, then you wont need to do this hacky disabling of the ssl